# Generics and inheritance - method args

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have written data structure LinkedList with method Add:

```
public class LinkedList<T>
    {
        private Element<T> first;
        private Element<T> last;

        public bool Add(Element<T> element)
        { 
        ...
```

I also have defined three classes:

```
public class Element<T> : IDisposable
public class ElementString : Element<string>, ICloneable    
public class ElementLong : Element<long>, ICloneable
```

When I want to do something like this in main method:

```
LinkedList<ElementLong> test = new LinkedList<ElementLong>();
ElementLong elem1 = new ElementLong();
test.Add(elem1);
```

I get the error that method Add "has some invalid arguments".
How to solve that problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I doubt a list element should be an IDisposable. Isn't it just a plain reference placeholder?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
LinkedList<ElementLong>
```

You define `T` as `ElementLong`. The `Add` method expects an `Element<T>`, which in this case is

```
Element<ElementLong>
```

If you want your list to allow only `long`s, you can use:

```
LinkedList<long> test = new LinkedList<long>();
ElementLong elem1 = new ElementLong();
test.Add(elem1);
```

Also, there's probably no need for the element derived classes, and you can use the base class directly:

```
var test = new LinkedList<long>();
var elem1 = new Element<long>();
test.Add(elem1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the generic type argument of the linked list to the actual type:

```
LinkedList<long> test = new LinkedList<long>();

ElementLong elem1 = new ElementLong();
test.Add(elem1);
```

Since `ElementLong` is actually a `Element<long>` this will work.

A `LinkedList<ElementLong>` will expect an `Element<ElementLong>` as argument, if you still get it :)

Comment: ElementLong will not be unused in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just in terms of an interface this:

```
LinkedList<ElementLong> test = new LinkedList<ElementLong>();
```

is likely equal to this:

```
LinkedList<Element<long>> test = new LinkedList<Element<long>>();
```

with type argument `T` equal to `Element<long>>`. This means that your `add` method effectively has a signature:

```
public bool Add(Element<Element<long>> element)
```

but your supplied argument is of type `Element<long>` instead of `Element<Element<long>>`.
You should declare your list to have generic type T equal to `long`, which is the type of element to be held within the list.

I doubt if Element class should be accessible (public) at all.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that your problem is that your generic type is `ElementLong` and therefore the `Add` method expects a value of `Element<ElementLong>`.  But I'd also say that you should consider changing the signature of your `Add` method to just take a value of `T`.

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private Element<T> first;
    private Element<T> last;

    public bool Add(T value)
    { 
    ...

LinkedList<long> test = new LinkedList<long>();
test.Add(0);
```

This is more inline with how other Generic Collections work.  You might also consider implementing the `IList<T>` interface.